i keep getting "Runtime exception at 0x004000ec: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000002" and the wrong output
.data
    # Define static matrix mymat consisting of 6x8 elements
    mymat: 
        .float 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0
        .float 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0
        .float 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0
        .float 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0
        .float 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0
        .float 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0

    # Prompt messages
    prompt_coll: .asciiz "Enter column number 1 (0-7): "
    prompt_col2: .asciiz "Enter column number 2 (0-7): "
    error_msg:   .asciiz "Invalid column number. Please enter a number between 0 and 7.\n"

.text
main:
    # Printing the elements of mymat
    la $t0, mymat    # Load base address of mymat into $t0
    li $t1, 0        # Initialize counter for printing elements

print_mymat_loop:
    lwc1 $f0, 0($t0)    # Load float value from mymat
    li $v0, 2           # System call code for printing float
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # Increment counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # Move to next element in mymat

    # Check if 8 values are printed, if not, print ":::" separator
    li $t2, 8
    beq $t1, $t2, print_newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sep_colons
    syscall
    j print_mymat_loop

print_newline:
    li $v0, 4       # Print newline
    la $a0, new_line
    syscall

    # Prompting user for coll and validating input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt_coll
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0   # Store coll in $s0

    # Validating coll input
    li $t3, 7       # Maximum column number
    bgt $s0, $t3, error_coll
    blt $s0, $zero, error_coll

    # Prompting user for col2 and validating input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt_col2
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0   # Store col2 in $s1

    # Validating col2 input
    bgt $s1, $t3, error_col2
    blt $s1, $zero, error_col2
    j swap_columns

error_coll:
    # Print error message for coll
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error_msg
    syscall
    j main

error_col2:
    # Print error message for col2
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error_msg
    syscall
    j main

swap_columns:
    # Swapping columns coll and col2 in mymat
    li $t4, 0        # Initialize row counter
swap_loop:
    beq $t4, 6, print_mymat_again   # If all rows processed, print mymat again
    mul $t5, $t4, 8    # Calculate offset for current row
    add $t6, $t5, $s0  # Calculate address of element in coll for current row
    lwc1 $f1, ($t6)    # Load element from coll
    add $t7, $t5, $s1  # Calculate address of element in col2 for current row
    lwc1 $f2, ($t7)    # Load element from col2
    swc1 $f1, ($t7)    # Store element from coll in col2
    swc1 $f2, ($t6)    # Store element from col2 in coll
    addi $t4, $t4, 1   # Increment row counter
    j swap_loop

print_mymat_again:
    # Printing the elements of mymat again after swapping
    la $t0, mymat    # Load base address of mymat into $t0
    li $t1, 0        # Initialize counter for printing elements

print_mymat_loop_again:
    lwc1 $f0, 0($t0)    # Load float value from mymat
    li $v0, 2           # System call code for printing float
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # Increment counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # Move to next element in mymat

    # Check if 8 values are printed, if not, print "$$"
    li $t2, 8
    beq $t1, $t2, print_newline_again
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sep_dollars
    syscall
    j print_mymat_loop_again

print_newline_again:
    li $v0, 4       # Print newline
    la $a0, new_line
    syscall

    # Creating a dynamic array and filling it with elements from row #4 of mymat
    li $t8, 8        # Number of elements in row #4
    li $v0, 9        # Allocate memory for dynamic array
    mul $a0, $t8, 4  # Calculate total bytes needed
    syscall
    move $s2, $v0    # Store base address of dynamic array in $s2
    la $t0, mymat    # Load base address of mymat into $t0
    li $t1, 0        # Initialize counter for filling dynamic array

fill_dynamic_array:
    add $t2, $t0, 32    # Address of the start of row #4
    lwc1 $f0, ($t2)     # Load element from row #4
    swc1 $f0, ($s2)     # Store element in dynamic array
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # Move to next element in row #4
    addi $s2, $s2, 4    # Move to next position in dynamic array
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # Increment counter
    bne $t1, $t8, fill_dynamic_array    # Repeat until all elements are filled

print_dynamic_array:
    # Printing dynamic array elements separated by one star #
    la $t0, ($s2)    # Load base address of dynamic array into $t0
    li $t1, 0        # Initialize counter for printing elements

print_dynamic_loop:
    lwc1 $f0, 0($t0)    # Load float value from dynamic array
    li $v0, 2           # System call code for printing float
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # Increment counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # Move to next element in dynamic array

    # Check if all elements are printed, if not, print "#"
    bne $t1, $t8, print_dynamic_loop
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sep_hash
    syscall

    # End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

.data 
sep_colons: .asciiz ":::"
sep_dollars: .asciiz "$$"
sep_hash: .asciiz "#"
new_line: .asciiz "\n"

this is the expected output:
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 :::9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 :::17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0 :::25.0 26.0 27.0 28.0 29.0 30.0 31.0 32.0 :::33.0 34.0 35.0 36.0 37.0 38.0 39.0 40.0 :::41.0 42.0 43.0 44.0 45.0 46.0 47.0 48.0 
Enter column number 1 (0-7): 2
Enter column number 2 (0-7): 5
1.0 2.0 7.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 3.0 8.0 :::9.0 10.0 15.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 11.0 16.0 :::17.0 18.0 23.0 20.0 21.0 22.0 19.0 24.0 :::25.0 26.0 31.0 28.0 29.0 30.0 27.0 32.0 :::33.0 34.0 39.0 36.0 37.0 38.0 35.0 40.0 :::41.0 42.0 47.0 44.0 45.0 46.0 43.0 48.0 
6.0 3.0 8.0 15.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 11.0 #```

this is what i have been getting:
0.0:::0.0:::0.0:::0.0:::0.0:::0.0:::0.0:::0.0
Enter column number 1 (0-7): 2
Enter column number 2 (0-7): 5

with a runtime error
Runtime exception at 0x004000ec: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000002
Go: execution terminated with errors.

Well, which line of code does address 0x004000ec correspond to? And how are you calculating the address that you're attempting to use on that line? Trace back from there until you find what you're doing wrong.

The error is self-explanatory, no?  Can you debug it?  These error can be detected by working backwards from the errer or by working forwards from some known good state before the error.

Your data looks ok, so probably error is in code, like missing or incorrect scaling on that access.

Btw, 0x0002 is a bad address altogether, so maybe just used the wrong register (the index or scaled_index instead of (scaled_index+base) for the source reg in that instruction.  Get to know your data, like where it is located in memory, so you can differentiate between a good address and a bad address.
